# VB Moving several indexes at one time

Tags: vb.net, loops

Just wanted to ask a question on moving several indexes of an array at once while in a sorting algorithm.

Basically I'm using a bubblesort algorithm (in VB.NET) to sort a list of data which contains names, height, weight and age. Each name is essentially associated with each extra piece of data. This data is sent in from a txt file and then sorted using the algorithm. This file can also be edited to add new names or pieces of data.

Is there a way I am able to associate the pieces of data so that when the array is sorted the data stays with the names while the names have been sorted alphabetically?

Example of how txt file is set out and sorting method:

Unsorted:

Monty Reyes

28

1700

70.7

Kier Burke

45

1800

93.5

Sorted:

Kier Burke

45

1800

93.5

Monty Reyes

28

1700

70.7

My current code is just a simple bubblesort which sorts the entire array.

```
Private Sub btnNameSort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNameSort.Click
    'turn the listbox items found in lstCurrentData to an array()
    Dim Data() As String = lstCurrentData.Items.Cast(Of Object).Select(Function(o) lstCurrentData.GetItemText(o)).ToArray
    Dim temp As String


    For ii = 0 To Data.Length - 2
        For i = 0 To Data.Length - 2
            If Data(i) > Data(i + 1) Then
                temp = Data(i)
                Data(i) = Data(i + 1)
                Data(i + 1) = temp
            End If
        Next
    Next
    For Each st In Data
        lstSortArray.Items.Add(st)
    Next
End Sub
```

If anyone has an idea on a way to create these associations within an array please inform me, I truly have no idea where to go from here. I tried to use Array.Copy but it got to complicated for me and I couldn't understand anything, I tried moving the new index in front of the name but then realised that would create an infinite loop. If there is a variable or something on this earth please just give me an idea of where to go. If anymore clarification is needed just ask. I'm still pretty new to VB so if I don't understand some terminology forgive me.

Comment: "... is there any way to integrate the class system in to a bubble sort? Like having the bubble sort use the class I create to sort by names in its loop?" Use a Class as suggested by Andrew Morton, then YES, you can bubble sort with the class.  Instead of `Dim Data() As String`, you'd have `Dim Data() As Person`. Then change your comparison from `If Data(i) > Data(i + 1) Then`, to `If Data(i).Name > Data(i + 1).Name Then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a class for the data ([Objects and classes in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/)), you can use LINQ ([Introduction to LINQ in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq)) to sort it on whichever property you like.

To demonstrate, I made this as a Console App for simplicity, and you will have to write the part to read in and parse the data from the file:

```
Module Module1

    Public Class Person
        Property Name As String
        Property Age As Integer
        Property Height As Integer
        Property Weight As Double

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("({0}: {1} years old, {2} mm, {3} kg)", Name, Age, Height, Weight)
        End Function

    End Class

    Public Sub ShowPeople(people As IEnumerable(Of Person))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, people))

    End Sub

    Public Sub BubbleSortPeopleByName(ByVal people As List(Of Person))
        For i = 0 To people.Count - 2
            Dim doneSwap = False
            For j = i + 1 To people.Count - 1
                If people(i).Name > people(j).Name Then
                    Dim tmp = people(j)
                    people(j) = people(i)
                    people(i) = tmp
                    doneSwap = True
                End If
            Next
            If Not doneSwap Then Return
        Next

    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim people As New List(Of Person)

        'TODO: Load the data from a file.
        people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "Monty Reyes", .Age = 28, .Height = 1700, .Weight = 70.7})
        people.Add(New Person With {.Name = "Kier Burke", .Age = 45, .Height = 1800, .Weight = 93.5})

        Console.WriteLine("Unsorted:-")
        ShowPeople(people)

        BubbleSortPeopleByName(people)

        Console.WriteLine("Sorted:-")
        ShowPeople(people)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
Unsorted:-
(Monty Reyes: 28 years old, 1700 mm, 70.7 kg)
(Kier Burke: 45 years old, 1800 mm, 93.5 kg)
Sorted:-
(Kier Burke: 45 years old, 1800 mm, 93.5 kg)
(Monty Reyes: 28 years old, 1700 mm, 70.7 kg)
```

The `Person` class has its own `.ToString()` method to make it easy to show an instance of `Person` as a string.

The `ShowPeople` method has `people As IEnumerable(Of Person)` as its parameter instead of a `List(Of Person)` because a List is an IEnumerable but not vice versa, and it makes it more versatile.

Comment: As this is for an assignment, I'm limited to what sorts I'm able to use, is there any way to integrate the class system in to a bubble sort? Like having the bubble sort use the class I create to sort by names in its loop?

Comment: @Cag1710_ In case you haven't worked it out yet, I added in a bubble sort. As you can see, all you need to do is compare just the Name property and swap the items if needed.

Comment: Side note: In `BubbleSortPeopleByName()`, I would change `ByRef people` to `ByVal people`.  "ByRef" here means you could create a completely new List WITHIN that method, assign it to the parameter variable called "people", and then the List OUTSIDE that method would now point to the new list as well.  This is probably not what is expected. It's certainly not necessary for just sorting the list.

Comment: I managed to successfully implement the class system, can’t thank you guys enough. The only problem I’m having now is at the very end of the sequence where I call the sub Bubblesort(people), since I need to paste the content into a listbox I’m unable to do somerthing like lstSortArray.Items.Add(BubbleSort(people)). I assumed once it was sorted through I could just call that routine. I was thinking of using a for loop of some sort but I’ll have to try that later.